# sequelize.import is not a function

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm new to express.

I want to import files to sequelize and declared:

```
const model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file))

                             ^
```

It returned the following type error

```
TypeError: sequelize.import is not a function
```

And then, edited code to

```
var model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize);

                                         ^
```

Then the error is:

```
TypeError: require(...) is not a function
```

I think it is the error in importing stuff....

Here is my whole file code:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const path = require('path');

const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const config = require('../config/config');

const db = {}

var __dirname = path.resolve();


const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    config.db.database,
    config.db.user,
    config.db.password,
    config.db.options
)


fs

    .readdirSync(__dirname)

    .filter((file) =>
        file !== 'index.js'
    )

    .forEach((file) => {

        //const model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file))

        var model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, 
Sequelize);

        db[model.name] = model

    })


db.sequelize = sequelize
db.Sequelize = Sequelize

module.exports = db
```

Comment: Did you look at `sequelize` variable at the line `const model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file))` using a breakpoint?

Comment: Seems like a syntax error. Follow the suggestion of @Anatoly and use breakpoints to track code flow. If you can't find share the whole code of the file.

Comment: how did you fix this, I have the same issue??

Comment: I haven't found a solution yet @bihireboris . I'm new to stack overflow and hoping someone to help.

Comment: Aight, will let know when I have some progress. keep up the learning

Comment: If you use something like

```js
export default (sequelize,DataTypes) => {...}
```

please make sure that you don't need to call the `default` function as

```js
 const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file)).default(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
```

Answer (score 121, accepted):

The error is caused by using the sequelize import object. Instead you should use Node's built in CommonJS `require` function. So change this line in your `models/index.js`:

```
const model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file))
```

to:

```
const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes)
```

You can also just regenerate the `models` directory and readd your models without the old `index.js` if you find that easier:

```
mv models models.bak && sequelize init:models && mv models.bak/index.js models.bak/index.js.bak && mv models.bak/* models/ && rm models.bak
```

That one liner will fix your problem if you have sequelize-cli installed globally. If you don't you can use this one:

```
npm i --save-dev sequelize-cli && mv models models.bak && npx sequelize init:models && mv models.bak/index.js models.bak/index.js.bak && mv models.bak/* models/ && rm models.bak
```

You may also need to update your config folder. I use a JavaScript config to inject ENVs, so I had to add to change my `const config = require(...` line to reflect that. If you used one of my one liners your old `models/index.js` file is now at index.js.bak if you need to grab any custom stuff from it.

Comment: Any idea what version this was removed? The sequelize guys really don't give a crap about breaking a known api, huh? (sigh)

Comment: @ChrisH I'm pretty sure it's version 6 and forward, but I have a vague memory seeing this somewhere in late version 5.

Comment: It was removed from v5 -> v6: [refactor: remove sequelize.import helper #12175](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/12175). Docs: [Upgrade to v6](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/upgrade-to-v6.html).
@DavidKamer I'm sorry, I don't understand how to change the `sequelize.import()` code into a v6 working code...

Comment: This works fine, but ESLint has a problem with the require statement inside of a function and not using a string literal, because of the rules `global-require` and `import/no-dynamic-require`. I disabled those two rules for the models/index.js but is there maybe a way to forEach() all the existing models in a prettier way? I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65185292/4790594), but it's not the prettiest solution either.

Comment: require isn't supported in esm.

Comment: @GregoryBologna if you mean your start script is being loaded with `esm` like 
`"start": "node -r esm app.js"`, you need to remove `"type": "module"` from your `package.json` specifications and you will be fine. This is because specifying type of module implies you can't use `require` anywhere even with esm. Once that is removed, `esm` will compile your code aptly.

Comment: `ReferenceError: require is not defined`.  How do we use the newer Sequelize with ES Modules?

Comment: When I updated using: `npm i sequelize@latest`, the app broke. ... `const model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file))` fixed my problem.

Comment: version>6 its   sequelize.define(path.join(__dirname, file))

Answer (score 17):

This might help someone else out there, in version `6.6.5` it's deprecated and you should replace it with `sequelize.define`.

Comment: Do you have the source where you found this?

Comment: sequelize.define(path.join(__dirname, file))

Answer (score 10):

As of now I was able to fix the issue by downgrading the sequelize module version in your package.json to `"sequelize": "^5.22.3",`. do let me know if it is also fixed on your side.

**Edit:** any sequelize version under `< 6.0.0` should work as normal

Comment: Should I have to downgrade all the dependencies also?

Comment: downgraded to sequelize@5.22.3, but unfortunately it didn't work.+-- body-parser@1.19.0
+-- cors@2.8.5
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY eslint@7.4.0
+-- eslint-plugin-vue@6.2.2
+-- express@4.17.1
+-- morgan@1.10.0
+-- mysql@2.18.1
+-- mysql2@2.1.0
+-- nodemon@2.0.4
+-- sequelize@5.22.3
`-- sqlite3@5.0.0......................................These r my modules

Comment: is it the same error you are getting back though?
also use `// const model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file))` in your index.js in models @Hot_Pink_Spin

Comment: Any idea what changed in version 6?

Comment: the `import` function was removed, check-out the major changes done on [version 6](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/upgrade-to-v6.html) @zwebie

Comment: Kindly look into using the approved answer for security and new features reasons @Godson

Answer (score 3):

in my case i replaced
this code

> const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))( sequelize,
> Sequelize.DataTypes );

with this :

> const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file)).default(sequelize,
> Sequelize.DataTypes);

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check that you do not have files in models directory that are not exporting anything.
2. Check that your exports are functions with same parameters as the instance it is being called in the require statement.

In any case like mine, I had empty files in my models directory.
*require(...)* is not a function simply because the index logic is iterating over and importing files that do not export anything from the models directory.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Oh god! thak you for this answer, it's a mistake dificult to find out the why. I had an empty file in models folder, after removing it, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have exported the model using old JavaScript syntax.

In my case, it was enough to change the code from:

```
export default (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    ...
}
```

to

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

People who tell downgrading not worked: Watch out for your index.js file!

For me downgrading to ^5.22.3 and changing

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    sequelize.define('User', {
        email: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            unique: true
        },
        password: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        }
    })

}
```

to

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) =>
    sequelize.define('User', {
        email: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            unique: true
        },
        password: DataTypes.STRING
    })
```

worked. That was the problem for me.

Comment: Those two code snippets are exactly the same!

Comment: They're not! In the first one, password is object with a key of type. In the second one, password is a String.