# Syncing sequelize models: sequelize.import() is not a function (and is deprecated)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js, discord.js

I'm trying to initialize a database using sqlite3 via the Sequelize.js ORM.  I have defined my three models (let's call them `model1`, `model2`, and `model3` and now I'm working on a js file that will initialize and sync my database.

`dbInit.js` looks like this:

```js
const Sequelize = require('../node_modules/sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'sqlite',
    logging: false,
    storage: 'database.sqlite',
});

// importing the modules
// import() is deprecated and will throw an error!
sequelize.import('models/model1');
sequelize.import('models/model2');
sequelize.import('models/model3');

// if force == true this will create the table, dropping it first if it already existed.
const force = process.argv.includes('--force') || process.argv.includes('-f');

// sync the database
sequelize.sync({ force }).then(async() => {
    console.log('dbInit.js: Database synced');
    sequelize.close();
}).catch(console.error);
```

When I run this file I observe the following error: `TypeError: sequelize.import is not a function`.  This error is quite clear, import is not a function!  This led me to discover [this page](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/models-definition.html) in the Sequelize documentation which states the following:

> Deprecated: sequelize.import
>
> Note: You should not use sequelize.import. Please just use require instead.

With that in mind here are my main questions:

**1: How do I tell Sequelize which models to include in my database during initialization?**
The documentation is pretty clear, I should 'just use require'.  But the documentation does not provide a clear example of the new convention.

**2: How do I correctly use require to include a model?**

I'm having trouble finding an example of how this works.  I'm new to JS so maybe this is super obvious, hence the lack of example.  I suppose we could do something like `const model1 = require(path/to/model1);`, can I then take that and plug it into the sync function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sequelize.import is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62917111/sequelize-import-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 3):

Kinda working on the same problem right now, just figured it out. Im using babel in my code for import, but you can just change them to require, if you don't.

You can import external modules to sequalize like that:
In your dbInit.js try:

```
// dbInit.js
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
import model1 from './model1'
import model2 from './model2'

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  process.env.DATABASE,
  process.env.DATABASE_USER,
  process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
  {
    dialect: 'sqlite',
  },
);

model1(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
model2(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);

const models = sequelize.models;

export { sequelize };

export default models;
```

model1 might look like this:

```
// model1.js
const message = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Message = sequelize.define('message', {
    text: DataTypes.STRING,
  });

  Message.associate = (models) => {
    Message.belongsTo(models.User);
  };

  return Message;
};

export default message;
```

Then you'll probably want to import your dbInit.js in your main index.js or something:

```
// index.js
import models, {sequelize} from './dbInit';

sequelize.sync({ force }).then(async () => {
  app.listen(process.env.PORT, () =>
    console.log(models)
  );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you can import your models like this.

```
const models = require('./models'); //path of models folder
const ModelA = models.model1;
const ModelB = models.model2;
const ModelC = models.model3;
```

`//Sequelize v5`

Now you don't have to import `Sequelize` as `models` folder has `index.js`

which will make a connection for you.

For using **sequelize** method. Just add **models** like this.

```
models.sequelize.sync({ force }).then(async() => {
    console.log('dbInit.js: Database synced');
    sequelize.close();
}).catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  What do you mean by 'models folder has index.js'?  My models folder has three .js files, each defining one model.  Are you saying that sequelize looks for index.js?

Comment: I'm able to get this to work if define my models inline (in the dbInit.js) file using `sequelize.define()`.  This sort of solves my problem, but I really would like to import external models.  I'll keep working on that.

Comment: If you are using sequelize cli. Then `sequelize init` creates three folders. `config` `models` `migration`. Above code will work with this way

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a workaround for my problem.  It's not my ideal solution as I would really like to be able to define external models and then bring them in as needed.  If anyone can find / show me a solid example of how this works

I ended up defining my models in-line within `dbInit.js` using the `sequelize.define()` method.  This is basically how they do it in the official Sequelize examples.  Checking this in a db browser for sqlite indicates that `dbInit.js` did create the required tables.

```js
// define a model...
sequelize.define('modelName',{
    random_thing:{
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        primaryKey: true,
    }
}, {
    timestamps: false,
});

// then sync the db...
```

I'm going to move on in this project look for a better solution down the road.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply import function in sequelize.js file like this

```
const dbConfig = require("../config/db.config")[process.env.NODE_ENV];

const Sequelize = require("sequelize");

const sequelize = new Sequelize(dbConfig.DB, dbConfig.USER, dbConfig.PASSWORD, {
  host: dbConfig.HOST,
  dialect: dbConfig.DIALECT,
  operatorsAliases: false,

});
const db = {};

db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
db.sequelize = sequelize;

db.model1= require("./model1")(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.model2 = require("./model2")(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.model3= require("./model3")(sequelize, Sequelize);

db.sequelize.sync({ force: true }).then(() => {
   console.log("Drop and re-sync db.");
});

module.exports = db;
```

I have imported all models  here and made a constant db which can be easily used.