# TypeError: sequelize.import is not a function

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am running into an error and I cannot find a solution to it:

```
C:\Users\student\Desktop\project\src\models\index.js:17
  User: sequelize["import"]('./user'),
                           ^

TypeError: sequelize.import is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\student\Desktop\project\src\models\/index.js:13:9)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Module._compile (C:\Users\student\Desktop\project\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:99:24)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (C:\Users\student\Desktop\project\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:104:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\student\Desktop\project\src\/index.js:9:1)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Here is the code:

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  process.env.DATABASE,
  process.env.DATABASE_USER,
  process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
  {
    dialect: 'postgres',
  },
);

const models = {
  User: sequelize.import('./user'),
  Message: sequelize.import('./message'),
};

Object.keys(models).forEach(key => {
  if ('associate' in models[key]) {
    models[key].associate(models);
  }
});

export { sequelize };

export default models;
```

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/node": "^7.12.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.7",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "apollo-server": "^2.19.0",
    "apollo-server-express": "^2.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "graphql": "^15.4.0",
    "pg": "^8.5.1",
    "sequelize": "^6.3.5",
    "uuid": "^8.3.1"
```

I am not sure the right direction to look to solve the issue. Any help is appreciated if you've run into something similar. I've added the dev dependencies in case that helps.

Comment: What version of sequelize are you using?

Comment: "sequelize": "^6.3.5",

Comment: can you import other things using "import", or sequelize is the first package you are importing in the project?

Comment: Plus, what version of Node.js are you using?

Comment: his main import statement works or he would not have gotten as far as he did

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sequelize.import is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62917111/sequelize-import-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i believe something has changed when they moved to 6.... check out this link.. or you could go back to 5.22.3 as suggested in this thread

[sequelize.import is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62917111/sequelize-import-is-not-a-function)

i am currently on 5.22.3 and i have the exact syntax as you and it works fine, but about to upgrade to six and will need to fix these problems as well..

Comment: Ok yeah going back to version 5.22.3 did fix the issue! It appears that v6 breaks stuff. Thanks for the tip it was very helpful!

Comment: no problem.. when i convert to 6 i will come back here and post what the changes are that you'll need... Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick for sequelize 6

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  process.env.DATABASE,
  process.env.DATABASE_USER,
  process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
  {
    dialect: 'postgres',
  },
);

const models = {
  User: require('./user')(sequelize, Sequelize),
  Message: require('./message')(sequelize, Sequelize),
};

Object.keys(models).forEach(key => {
  if ('associate' in models[key]) {
    models[key].associate(models);
  }
});

export { sequelize };

export default models;
```

Comment: Thank you, this is so clean and accurate.