# Error : TypeError: sequelize.import is not a function

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, discord.js

I have a problem with this code

```
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize')
const path = require('path');

const sequelize = new Sequelize({
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'sqlite',
    storage: path.resolve("Storage", "database.sqlite"),
    logging: false
});

const Guild = sequelize.import("Guild");

module.exports = {
    Guild
};
```

The problem is the : "const Guild = sequelize.import("Guild");"
I have this error : TypeError: sequelize.import is not a function

*(I put a little part of my index.js)*

```
client.commands = new Discord.Collection
client.aliases = new Discord.Collection
client.cooldowns = new Discord.Collection

client.database = require(require("path").resolve("Database"))
client.database.Guild.sync({force: false})
```

Comment: The method was deprecated and removed check your version

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sequelize.import is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62917111/sequelize-import-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/models-definition.html) says that you need to use require instead of import.

[image]