# How to resolve sequelize.import is not a function?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

i want to import files to sequelize but i have this error which i can't resolve TypeError: sequelize.import is not a function

This is my code

db.js in config directory

```
const {Sequelize } = require('sequelize')

const sequelize = new Sequelize("ebooks", "root", "", {
    dialect: "mysql",
    host: "localhost",
    define: {
        timestamps: true
    }
})
module.exports = sequelize
```

index.js file in models directory

```
const sequelize = require('../config/db.js')
const Users = sequelize.import('Users',require('./Users.js'))

module.exports = {
    Users,
    connection: sequelize
};
```

Users.js file in models

```
module.exports=(sequelize, DataTypes)=>{
    return sequelize.define('Users',{
        userName: DataTypes.STRING,
        email:DataTypes.STRING,
        password: DataTypes.STRING,
        firstName: DataTypes.STRING,
        lastName: DataTypes.STRING,
        role:{ type: DataTypes.STRING,
                default: 'user'
         },
         thumbnail :DataTypes.TEXT
    },{
        underscored:true
    })
}
```

My middleware to reset database in controllers directory

```
const connection = require('../models/index.js').connection

const resetDatabase = async (req, res) => {
    await connection.sync({
        force: true
    })
    .then(() => {
        res.status(201).send({
            message: 'Database reset'
        })
    })
    .catch(() => {
        res.status(500).send({
            message: 'Error during database resetting'
        })
    })
};

module.exports = {
   resetDatabase
}
```

Hope you can help me! Thanks

Comment: Looks like it's [deprecated](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/models-definition.html).

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63275525/7574023)

Comment: Can you past you error log also.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sequelize.import is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62917111/sequelize-import-is-not-a-function)