# Sequelize v6 - TypeError: sequelize.import is not a function

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am using ES Modules with `"type": "module"` in my package.json.  And I have upgraded to the latest version of Sequelize as of right now(6.6.2).

I am having an issue with this line of code:

```js
const model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file));
```

That is in my index.js in my models folder.  I discovered that Sequelize removed the 'import' function in v6 (https://sequelize.org/master/manual/upgrade-to-v6.html).  And I found this answer on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63275525/571723

I tried switching to `const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes)` from that answer.  But that I got an error stating `require is not defined`.  So that is where I am stuck now.  It seems like by forcing you to use 'require', Sequelize took a step backwards, as I thought ES modules with 'import' was the current and future best practice for Node.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're right. After [upgrading Sequelize from v5 to v6](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/upgrade-to-v6.html#sequelize) there was removed "import" method at least. So try something like this:

```
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize('db_name', 'db_user', 'db_pass', {});

const modelPath = path.join(__dirname, './path/to/model/file');
const model = require(modelPath).default(sequelize, Sequelize);
```

Comment: And how do I do that last line without a `require`?

Comment: @dmikester1 `import MyModel from './db/MyModel.js'` then you can use `MyModel` after that

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
const model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file));
```

With

```
const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes)
```